# How to use certificate with Graph API to get Groups user belongs to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Can someone show me how to get group names that currently signed in user belong to in ASP.NET Core 7 ?

Note that I'm using a certificate and not client secret to access Azure AD. Most of the examples I've come across are using client secret but none show how to do this using a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Self-Signed** certificate using PowerShell:

```bash
$certname = "testruk"    
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.cer"
```

[image]

Now, export the above certificate to **`.pfx`**:

```bash
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -Force -AsPlainText 
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.pfx" -Password $mypwd
```

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Application** and uploaded the **`.cer`** certificate:

[image]

And granted API permissions:

[image]

To **authenticate to the Azure AD Application using certificate**, I used the below code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;  
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\**\\Desktop\\testruk.pfx", "password");

string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID";
string clientId = "ClientID"; /
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};


IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder  
.Create(clientId)  
.WithAuthority(authority)  
.WithCertificate(certificate)  
.Build();

var authRequestUrl = confidentialClientApplication.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(scopes);
string authorizationCode = "AuthorizationCodeFromRedirect";
AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();
  
Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", authResult.AccessToken);
```

**The Access token generated successfully:**

[image]

When I decoded the access token, the **scopes** are displayed:

[image]

By using the above access token, you can call the Microsoft Graph API.

**For sample**, I used Postman to list the details of signed-in user using the above generated access token:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List a user's direct memberships - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254789/discussion-on-answer-by-rukmini-how-to-use-certificate-with-graph-api-to-get-gro); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.