# .Net core 6 API authentication with client credentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-identity

API's authentication configfiguration code looks like the following:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(jwtBearerOptions =>
                                    { }, msIdentityOptions =>
                                    {
                                        configuration.Bind("AzureAd", optionsB);
                                        var defaultBackChannel = new HttpClient();
                                        defaultBackChannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "shard-manager");
                                        msIdentityOptions.Backchannel = defaultBackChannel;
                                        
                                    })
                                    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(e => { })
                                    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I want to authenticate using a client Id and client secret and call and endpoint in the API. I can authenticate the app registration azure successfully but when I use the access token to send request to the API it returns 401 unauthorized.

I get the same 401 result when I send the request using postman with access token.

App registration:

[image]

[image]

Postman:

[image]

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: What API you are trying to call? and can you include Postman screenshots

Comment: @Rukmini The API I wrote with the above api authentication configuration code.

Comment: @Rukmini I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note** that: As you are using Client credential flow, you have to grant application permissions. For delegated type permissions you have to make use of any user interactive flow such as Authorization code flow.

I created an **Azure AD Application and exposed an API** like below:

[image]

When the scope is added in the API permission blade it is **delegated** type:

[image]

Now I generated access token using **Client Credential Flow** via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://ClientID/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, **scope is not displayed**:

[image]

When I called the API, I got **401 unauthorized** error:

```json
GET https://apiendpoint/weatherforecast
```

[image]

*If you want to use Client credential flow only then create **App roles**:*

[image]

Now the role is added as **Application type** permissions:

[image]

I generated the **access token** and when decoded it displays the role:

[image]

***Otherwise***, for **delegated API permissions** make use of Authorization Code Flow:

Generated **auth-code** using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://ClientID/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

***When I decoded the access token, scopes displayed like below:***

[image]

**I am able to call the API successfully:**

```json
GET https://apiendpoint/weatherforecast
```

[image]

- Make sure to update **`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`** property set to 2 in the manifest.

You can refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781696/how-to-use-certificate-with-graph-api-to-get-groups-user-belongs-to/76787778#76787778) by me for sample code for Authorization Code Flow by changing the scope.

**Reference:**

[azureactive-directory-aspnetcore-webapp· GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) by *jennyf19*

Comment: It is worth noting, even though for some it may be obvious, that the role has to be added to the client that is requesting the token.