# Accesing endpoint from browser is working but not from postman

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-azure

i have a question regarding the testing flow for accesing a resorce(an endpint in a java spring cloud application) secured by Azure Active Directory.
So when i am accesing the resource from browser its redirecting me to microsoft page i paste my crdentials and i am loging in sucesfuly and after that i can acces that resource. But if i am trying to do the same with postman so first of all i need to get the acces token.
[image]

The get response:
[image]

After i get the acess token i put it in the Authorization header with Bearer in front, but its returning me the html sign form and whats intersting when i am trying to get request my endpoint resource its redirecting to sign in form and this is why its returning the form.
The form is send also when i am trying to get request the resorce (200 status code in both cases with or without token)

I am kinda blocked by this and i am tried many things but its just not work

The spring app has just an controller returning the string "Hello" and has an application.properties;

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  port: 9191

spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile:
          tenant-id: TENANTID
        credential:
          client-id: CLIENTID
          client-secret: CLIENTSECRET
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which resource are you trying to access using access token?

Comment: The endpoint that is created in my spring boot app , its just a simple controller with endpoint"http://localhost:8080/api/welcome" that is returning a string

Comment: its Application ID URI made in azure active directory in my app(i only have 1 registered there) so its: Application ID URI/read

Comment: Can you try using the 'authorization' tab and select authentication type 'Basic Authentication' in the postman and call the API? Otherwise can you use https://web.postman.co/ and try

Comment: its getting me the same sign in form

Comment: thats not an error but its the sign in form from microsoft i guess because itrs redirecting from my endpoint to that sign in form but yes its same 200

Comment: While generating the access token can you click on Authorize using browser and generate access token? Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/Leqsa7q.png).

Comment: In my previous thread I was able to call the web API using Authorization code flow successfully check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873643/net-core-6-api-authentication-with-client-credentials

Comment: yeah , but i mean in your case you got unauthorized , i do not get something like this , i got the sign in form with status code 200, this is why i do not understand why its happening

Comment: Yes can you follow the same steps and check if it working?

Comment: so i got the acces code with the token endpoint but its still not working , the same cursed sign in form with 200 status code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255594/discussion-between-rukmini-and-imatabil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the app was not an spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server but an spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client