# App Permission to Azure API (Client Credential Flow)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular (MSAL) + ASP.NET Core Web API with AAD. This setup is working and the UI is able to reach API's fine. However, I now have a back-end process that needs to call into the same ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I wrote a method that I successfully get a token from but when I present this token to the API it says unauthorized. I changed the scope to intended scope and it still fails. Any reason why?

```
    public AccessTokenModel GetAccessTokenModelSameClient()
    {
        string url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mytenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        var clientId = "{API_CLIENT_ID}";
        string grant_type = "client_credentials";
        string clientSecret = "mysecret";
        string scope = $"api://{Client_ID_For_API}/.default";
        var body = $"grant_type={grant_type}&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={scope}";

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent).Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenModel>(json);
            }
            else
            {
                var error = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                throw new ApplicationException(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to get an access token with your code, print it's value while debugging and copy it to this [web site](https://jwt.io/). By using this site you will be able to decode the token value and see it in clear text. Check the value of the audience claim (aud), the value of the token expiration and the value of the scope claim. Ensure all of them have the expected value (based on the configuration of your API service and the authorization policies you set for your endpoints)

Comment: In order to further clarify your question you can also post here the access token payload value you get with the above mentioned procedure. Just remember to remove any sensitive data (e.g.: the email claim of the user if any)

Comment: The most important claims for the authentication are the aud claim (which must match the audience you set for your API service) and the token expiration (of course a token must not be expired in order to be considered valid by your API service). The scope claim is used instead to apply the authorization policies.

Comment: 1)Define the required permissions in the Azure AD app registration for the API and request the correct scope when you get the access token.2)Make sure that the Client ID and Secret you are using are correct and associated with the API you are trying to access3)Check if the obtained access token contains the correct roles and permissions. You can use a tool such as [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode the JWT token and view its contents.4)In your ASP.NET Core API, ensure that the middleware used to validate tokens is properly configured

Comment: If you are using delegated scope, then make use of Authorization code flow not Client credential flow. And make sure that the scope/roles is present when you decode the token.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note** that: If you are using delegated API permissions to call the API then, you have to generate access token using interactive flow such as Authorization code flow. Client credential flow is used for Application type API permissions.

I exposed an API and granted **Admin consent to the API permissions; it is added as delegated API permission**.

[image]

Now, I generated access token via Postman using Client Credential flow:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://xxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) the `scp` is not displayed:

[image]

Hence you are getting unauthorized error as you are making use of Client credential flow to generate access token for delegated API permission.

**To resolve the error,** generate access token using Authorization code flow:

Generate the **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxx/api.access
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://xxx/api.access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **`scp`** is displayed:

[image]

Now you can call the API with the above generated access token.

***To do the same in C#, refer the below:***

[c# - How to use certificate with Graph API to get Groups user belongs to - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781696/how-to-use-certificate-with-graph-api-to-get-groups-user-belongs-to/76787778#76787778)by me

[Using MSAL.NET to get tokens by authorization code (for web sites) - Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/authorization-codes)